# How to show list object page in Android?

Tags: android

I have trouble in my listing program. How to show list object data on web in Android? this is my code:

```
public void loadData() {
    String data = txtSeach.getText().toString();
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextView);
    String result = "";
    // the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("search", data));
    InputStream is = null;
    // http post
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.grouprecipes.com/search");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.grouprecipes.com/"
                + data + "/");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
        textView.append(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // parse json data
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            // JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            // textView.setTag(json_data);
            // textView.getContext();

            /*
             * Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
             * ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
             * ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
             * ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
             * 
             * );
             */
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP POST request to `http://www.grouprecipes.com/` is returning HTML not JSON.

Comment: yes... how to make this a JSON and finished view in my apps use a list.. please help me... thanks

Comment: HTML is not JSON and you can not easily make it JSON. Ask the site operator to provide this data as JSON.